# How to process a record in Kafka based on the processing result of another record?

Tags: apache-kafka, synchronization

I have a `@KafkaListener` class that listens to a particular topic and consumes records that contain either a `Person` object or a `Phone` object (and only one of them). Every `Phone` has a reference / correlation id to the corresponding `Person`. The listener class performs certain validations that are specific to the type received, saves the object into a database and produces a transfer success / failed response back to Kafka that is consumed by another service.

So a `Person` can successfully be transferred without any corresponding `Phone`, but a `Phone`  transfer should only succeed if the corresponding `Person` transfer has succeeded. I can't wrap my head around how to implement this "synchronization", because `Person`s and `Phone`s get into Kafka independently as separate records and it's not guaranteed that the `Person` corresponding to a particular `Phone` will be processed before the `Phone`.

Is it at all possible to have such a synchronization given the current architecture or should I redesign the producer and send a `Person` / `Phone` pair as a separate type?

Thanks.

Comment: do people and phones come in on a single, unified, input topic, or are  these 2 separate input topics? is there any indication on a `Person` whether or not this person is expected to have a matching phone or not?

Comment: @radai Yes, people and phones are processed within a single topic. The record has an indication within itself whether the payload contained in the record is a person or a phone object - this is how the listener understands how to deserialize the payload. And no - a Person has no knowledge of the relating Phone, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how you're using the same serializer for different object types, but you should probably create separate topics and/or branch your current one into two (refer Kafka Streams API)

I assume there are less people than phones, in which case you could build a KTable from a people topic, then as you get phone records, you can perform a left join or lookup against this table for some person ID

Other solutions could involve using Kafka Connect to dump records into a system where you can do the join